# LINQ for (recursively or not) finding all the childrens, starting from a parent

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a table structured like

```
Application_OID
Status
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID
```

The RecommendedFromApplication_OID will contain Application_OID of the object it was last recommended from. For example, there is an application

```
Application_OID = 1
Status = New
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = null
```

This application is recommended for another job, another application would be created with the following values

```
Application_OID = 2
Status = New
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = 1
```

and the **Status** of the first object would be updated to

```
Application_OID = 1
Status = Recommended
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = null
```

Let's say I recommend the newly created for another job, a new entry would be created with the following values

```
Application_OID = 3
Status = New
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = 2
```

And the 2nd application would be updated to Recommended, the final data would be

```
Application_OID = 1
Status = Recommended
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = null

Application_OID = 2
Status = Recommended
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = 1

Application_OID = 3
Status = New
{some other fields}
RecommendedFromApplication_OID = 2
```

In this way, I would be able to recommend an application for as many times I want to.

Now the problem; I would like to write a function in LINQ, which would take an Application_OID and would return List containing the IDs of all its recommended (child) applications' Application_OID, like

```
private List<int> GetRecommendedIds(int id)
{
    var applicationIds = (/*some query*/).ToList();
    return applicationIds;
}
```

Then calling

```
GetRecommendedIds(1)
```

would return a list of int with values

```
2,3
```

Comment: That's why such table structure is the worst choice, if you're planning to execute queries like "get all hierarchy from the parent". Can you change it?

Comment: I am afraid I can not, we have a huge data in production.

Comment: Let's say you have another Application `4` RecommendedFrom `2`, and another `A5R1`, `A6R5` and `A7R5`. Would your expected result be `2,3,4,5,6,7` (depth first) or `2,5,3,4,6,7` (breath first), or does the actual sequence not matter?

Comment: Sequence does not matter, and one application can only be recommended from one application, so every parent will must have one child only

Comment: I think you're mixing the parent/child terms. In the scenario, you describe, `1` is the parent of `2` and `2` is the parent of `3`. In my extended scenario, `2` is also the parent of `4` and `5` is the parent of `6` and `7` (and a child of `1`). One application can only be recommended by *one* other application, but different applications can be recommended by the *same* application, right?

Comment: no, not more than one applications can be recommended by the same application

Comment: I solved it by writing a do while loop with linq in it, but I would want an efficient solution using just linq. I am posting my answer as well.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui - Yes, I think I understood that. But one application can *recommend* more than one other application, right? `1` recommends `2`, so `2` is "recommendedFrom" `1`. Now `42` recommends `2`, so now `2` is "recommendedFrom" `42` (and *not* `1` anymore). But then `42` also recommends `99`. At this point, both `2` and `99` are *both* "recommendedFrom" `42`, right?

Comment: @Corak We are talking about application, applications are recommended for another JOB, but the newly created applications contain reference to the last application it has been recommended from. Once an application is recommended, it is disabled and cannot be recommended any further. So now, if we want to recommend the new one, only the newly created application would be recommended and no changes would be done to the old application(s). Am I clear now?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<int> GetRecommendedForApplication(int Application_OID)
    {
        var recommendedApplications = new List<int>();
        var context = new SomeEntities();
        int applicationId = Application_OID;
        Application application;
        do
        {
            application = (from applications in context.Applications
                           join recommendedApplication in context.Applications
                               on applications.Application_OID equals
                               recommendedApplication.ParentApplication_OID
                               where recommendedApplication.ParentApplication_OID == applicationId
                           select recommendedApplication.Application_OID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (application != null)
            {
                recommendedApplications.Add(application);
                applicationId = application.Application_OID;
            }
        } while (application != null && application.ParentApplication_OID != null);

        return recommendedApplications;
    }
```